# XMLHttpRequest.responseText

Tags: javascript, ajax

Usually if we want to get some data with `AJAX` we do something like that:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200){
        elem.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;          
    }
}
```

And the question is - can we get the result not as `elem.innerHTML` but as is?

I mean:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200){
        xhr.responseText;           
    }
}
```

The problem is that result of my query is HTML-table made by PHP and I don't want to wrap it with some other elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
elem.innerText = xhr.responseText;
```

Watch out though: the innerText property is read-only on the html, table, tBody, tFoot, tHead, and tr objects.  When the innerText property is set, the given string completely replaces the existing content of the object.

Comment: But there is result also will be inside some element. So as I understand that what I want is impossible

Comment: you can just do `document.body.innerHTML` if you want to set the entire page to be the returned contents.  It just won't evaluate any javascript unless you use jquery's .html() method such as `$(body).html(xhr.responseText);` or `$(elem).html(xhr.responseText);`.